# Checking for null in dynamic elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, xml-parsing

I am loading a string into an xml element and have instituted what I thought what adequate error checking, however if a particular xml node isnt present it still throws an error

```
StackTrace "at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n 
at MvcApplication1.Controllers.MyController.MySearch(SearchModel s)
in c:\\...Controller.cs:line 2900" string e {"Sequence contains no elements"}   
System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

If this isnt the correct way to check for the existence of a node, what is? Please advise and thanx in advance.

```
      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(mytextstring);
            XDocument docx = DocumentToXDocumentReader(doc);
    ...
            try
            {
                foreach (XElement xe in docx.Descendants("RootElement"))
                {

                    MySearchModel jbcs = new MySearchModel();

                    jbcs.ID = xe.Attribute("SID").Value;                        
                    ...
                    jbcs.FirstName = (xe.Element("PersonalData").Element("Name").Element("First") == null) ? "" : 
                    xe.Element("PersonalData").Element("Name").Element("First").Value.Trim();

                    jbcs.LastName = (xe.Element("PersonalData").Element("Name").Element("Last") == null) ? "" :
                    xe.Element("PersonalData").Element("Name").Element("Last").Value.Trim();  

                    jbcs.HomeLocation = (xe.Element("PersonalData").Element("Address").Element("Location") == null) ? "" :
                    xe.Element("PersonalData").Element("Address").Element("Location").Value.Trim(); 
        ...
       }
    }
```

This doesnt work either:

```
jbcs.FirstName = (xe.Element("PersonalData").Element("Name").Element("First").Equals(null)) ? ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to modify it a bit:

```
bool hasCompany = xe.Element("Experiences").DescendantsAndSelf("Experience").Descendants("Company").Any();
jbcs.RecentEmployer = (hasCompany ? xe.Element("Experiences").DescendantsAndSelf("Experience").Descendants("Company").First().Value.Trim() : "");
bool hasJobTitle = xe.Element("Experiences").DescendantsAndSelf("Experience").DescendantsAndSelf("Job").Descendants("Title").Any();
jbcs.RecentJobTitle = (hasJobTitle ? xe.Element("Experiences").Element("Experience").DescendantsAndSelf("Job").Descendants("Title").First().Value.Trim() : "" );
```

Dont know if this is the best way, but it works.